# Check If Two Lines Are Exactly Parallel or Not?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, lines

Lines are in the form:

```
A1 x + B1 y = C1
A2 x + B2 y = C2
```

I am Checking:

```
A1*B2-A2*B1 != 0
```

But I want That The Lines Should Be Exactly Parallel Not Same

P.S. - Only Checking `A1*B2-A2*B1` will also give Coincident Lines.

Comment: Add another check that they are not the same.  That would just be comparing some ratios between the two lines.

Comment: i am using A1*C2 - A2*C1 !=0 and B1*C2 - B2*C1 !=0

Comment: but it is not handling the Case Like : lines parallel to X axis or Y axis

Comment: conceptually you can use `arctan`.  Performance wise you are probably better off to just handle the special cases.  As a programming matter you should know not to rely on an exact equality with floating point operations.  This doesn't seem to have anything to do with mathematica,can you delete that tag?

Comment: @agentp how will i handle cases like 3*x = 1 and 4*x = 2

Comment: `if b1==0 and b2==0 and c1/a1 != c2/a2`   (presuably we already reject cases of `a==0 and b==0` as invalid lines.)

Comment: Are you trying to figure this out in a floating point context? Or are you looking for arbitrary precision? I.e. are you looking for a computed answer (where close enough is good enough) or a mathematically exact answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that

```
A1 x + B1 y = C1
A2 x + B2 y = C2
```

Are parallel if and only if `A1*B2 - B1*A2 == 0`.

Supposing that they are parallel, you want to determine whether or not they are distinct.

Note that if  `A1*B2 - B1*A2 == 0` then there exists a constant, `k`, with `A1*k = A2` and `B1*k = B2`. This constant can be computed as `k = A2/A1` or `k = AB/B1`. Care must be taken to not divide by `0`. You can't have both `A1` and `B1` be equal to `0` in a line, thus you can use (pseudocode):

```
if A1 != 0 then k = A2/A1 else k = B2/B1
```

Once you determine `k`, check if `C1*k == C2`. If this equality holds then the lines are identical, if not, they are parallel but distinct.

As usual, some care must be taken with floating point operations. It isn't a bad idea to check e.g. `abs(C1*k - C2) < 0.00000001` rather than `C1*k == C2`.

Comment: will it handle cases like C1=0 or C2=0

Comment: i am checking : if (A1*C2 - A2*C1)!=0 or (A1*C2 - A2*C1)!=0 then Lines Are Distinctly Parallel          .. Is It Right ?

Comment: @uder7 It should handle cases like C1 = 0 and C2 = 0. If the two expressions on the LHS are constant multiples of each other than the lines coincide if and only if the RHS are the same constant multiple of each other. The special case when C1 = C2 = 0 corresponds to the case where the lines pass through the origin. Two parallel lines passing through the origin coincide with each other. I'm not quite sure about your second question -- I think it is correct if you mean `B1,B2` in the second expression rather than `A1,A2`

Comment: how to check negative slopes

Comment: That would just be `A1*B1 < 0`